# Display Google Maps Icon instead of position dynamically

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, gridview

I'm working on an application that shows the position of vehicles based on the signals the GPS device sends. I have a gridview in ASP.Net that displays that info based on parameters using stored procedures and then populating the gridview with:

```
DataSetTableAdapters.sp_GetPositionTableAdapter gp = new DataSetTableAdapters.sp_GetPositionTableAdapter
gridview.DataSource=  gp.GetData(parameters)
```

The columns are: Time of arrival, Address, Position (Latitude, Longitude). But instead of displaying the position like this >> "32.546750000000000, -116.947848333333000", I would like to show an icon that redirects to the google map page with the position of the vehicle marked. Or maybe display a pop-up.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to to output anchor tag with href='http://maps.google.com/maps?q=32.546750000000000, -116.947848333333000'

The best way would be to learn how to use the Google Maps API and create a Marker on the map at the proper location.

Simple example:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #map_canvas { height: 100%; }
    @media print {
        html, body { height: auto; }
        #map_canvas { height: 650px; }
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng =
        new google.maps.LatLng(32.546750000000000, -116.947848333333000);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng, 
        map: map,
        title: "Hello World!"
    });
}

if (window.addEventListener) { // W3C standard
    window.addEventListener('load', initialize, false); // NB **not** 'onload'
}
else if (window.attachEvent) { // Microsoft
    window.attachEvent('onload', initialize);
} 
</script>

<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 400px; width: 800px;"></div>
```

Comment: Nice example. This is _very_ minor, but while I was sprucing up the code formatting, I noticed that you have multiple style definitions for `map_canvas`. I didn't want to mess with that part, but you may want to do a little tidying up; I wasn't sure if there was something you were trying to highlight, so I left it as you wrote it.

Comment: The second definition is for the print @media definition.  This is used when the output is the printer and not the screen.  Glad the sample was helpful...it is actually taken straight from the Google Maps API example...

Comment: @ChrisStater, Thanks for you help. I'm using a simple anchor tag and it's working OK. But I was wondering, is there a way to display the google map page on the "Map" view and not "Satellite" by default?

Comment: Try the following:  **http://maps.google.com/maps?q=32.546750000000000,+-116.947848333333000&hl=en&t=m&z=17**

Comment: Check out [QueryString for Google Maps](http://querystring.org/google-maps-query-string-parameters/)  it will show all the options (as of Aug 2011) for query string parameters for Google Maps.  The one you are most interested in is t=m|k|h|p WHERE: m=map, k=Sat., h=Hybrid, p=Terrain